# iAd banners producing blank space when using canDisplayBannerAds on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, iad

I have a UITableView that I'm calling `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES` in `viewDidAppear`. When the ads display, extra space appears at the bottom of the table view equal to the height of the iAd. When the ad hides, the extra space vanishes.

Just to note, I am using AutoLayout.

For complete clarification, here is the only piece of code relating to iAd in my entire project:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
}
```

[image: Image showing relevant problem]

I've got no idea what could be causing this. I've tried moving the `canDisplayBannerAds` around to no avail.

Comment: are you using auto layout? if there is no ad displayed, is there white space at the bottom?

Comment: I am indeed using AutoLayout. When no ad is displayed, the space disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. It's most likely the size of the UITabBar. Coming off Apple's [WWDC session](http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/613):

> And what this does is it takes the root view, or the top level view of
>   your View Controller, and it becomes the originalContentView.

Edit: Found the answer. Set the TabBar to "Opaque Tab Bar" and everything is fixed

Comment: I guess that's a bug in Apple's code then. It's a shame, I like the translucent tab bar.